# When adding a Filter to My SSRS Report, I lose records

Tags: reporting-services, filter, null, missing-data, spaces

I’m trying to add a filter to my report. The field is text and in the application, users can type in whatever they want. Some records have Null in this field and some have spaces. 
In the Stored Procedure, if this field contains NULL I set it to ‘ NULL’ and if the field is spaces I set it to ‘ Blank’ using Select CASE fieldname WHEN ‘’ then ‘ Blank’ ELSE ISNULL(fieldname, ‘ NULL’) END as fieldname. 
For the filter choices I created a dataset using the same Select CASE logic and order by fieldname to get the Null and Blank to the top (or close to the top since some records have leading spaces in this field). 
I created the parameter using Data Type Text and Allow multiple values.
When I create the filter in the reports Tablix properties, I use the Expression fieldname, Operator In, and in the Value field try to select the parameter. The parameter is there but when selected does not show in the Value field. I can type it in as [@ParameterName] and it stays but why would it not select?
When I run the report it is missing several records none of which had NULL or spaces in this field. 
I’ve spent a lot of hours reading different postings and trying different things but have not been able to solve this issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, thank you.
The issue was that some of the records with the same text in the field had trailing spaces and some did not. When creating the filter, Report Builder used the text with trailing spaces and therefore would not match the records where the text did not have trailing spaces thereby eliminating these records from the report.